# Speed up complex loop and group by in R for large data set

Tags: r, performance, loops, dataframe, dplyr

I have a below mentioned code:

```
    library(dplyr)

# Create sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:6,
  SR1 = c(123,124,125,125,785,849),
  SR2 = c("as#12.c", "ae&14.v", "at$19.e", "at$19.d", "ab&22.n", "ab&22.n"),
  DRC1 = c("ABC-1", "ABC-1", "AXX-1", "AXX-1", "AWZ-2", "AWZ-5"),
  DX2 = c("SXI", "SXI", NA, "SCV", "DDF", "DDF"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Create a function to give Status with each kind of DRC1 according to your rules
StatusJudge <- function(df_sub) {
  if (dim(df_sub)[1] == 1) {
    df_sub$Status <- FALSE
  }
  else {
    if (all(!is.na(df_sub$DX2))) {
      df_sub$Status <-
        ifelse(length(unique(df_sub$DX2)) == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
    }
    else {
      df_sub$Status <-
        ifelse(length(unique(df_sub$SR1)) == 1 | length(unique(df_sub$SR2)) == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
      if (any(!is.na(df_sub$DX2))) {
        df_sub$IDfound[is.na(df_sub$DX2)] <-
          df_sub$ID[!is.na(df_sub$DX2)][1]
      }
    }
  }
  return(df_sub)
}

# Apply the StatusJudge to each element of df_list and then combine the results
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Status = NA, IDfound = NA) %>%
  group_by(DRC1) %>%
  do(StatusJudge(.)) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

Which gives below mentioned output:

```
ID    SR1     SR2  DRC1   DX2  Status IDfound
<int> <dbl>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <lgl>   <int>
  1    123   as#12.c ABC-1  SXI   TRUE      NA
  2    124   ae&14.v ABC-1  SXI   TRUE      NA
  3    125   at$19.e AXX-1 <NA>   TRUE       4
  4    125   at$19.d AXX-1  SCV   TRUE      NA
  5    785   ab&22.n AWZ-2  DDF  FALSE      NA
  6    849   ab&22.n AWZ-5  DDF  FALSE      NA
```

The problem here is i have a big dataset (~1 million Rows), where it's taking too much time even after waiting almost 4 hours i didn't get output. but the same code is working fine for small data set (~10K Rows etc.).

Please help to speedup this code.

Comment: I don't think `StatusJudge` is the slow part. Try it with e.g., `StatusJudge <- function(df_sub) {df_sub$Status <- TRUE; df_sub}`. If that is slow then there is little point in optimizing `StatusJudge`. You'll probably want to use `data.table` instead of `dplyr` for faster grouped transformation.

Comment: @Ista Not worked, can you optimize my code for faster performance??

Comment: Please, describe verbally what the code is intended to do and what the underlying rules are which are mentioned in a code comment. Without this, it is difficult to re-engineer the given code by just comparing with the expected result of a rather small sample dataset. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test this `data.table` approach with your production data. I have tried to convert the nested `if ... else` and `ifelse()` statements into a boolean expression.

This seems to work as expected for the small sample dataset but needs thorough testing with more test cases.

```
library(data.table)

# use boolean expressions instead of if ... else clauses to create Status
setDT(df)[, Status := .N != 1L && 
            (all(!is.na(DX2)) && uniqueN(DX2 == 1L) ||
               any(is.na(DX2)) && (uniqueN(SR1) == 1L || uniqueN(SR2) == 1L)), by = DRC1][]

# append IDfound column
# create lookup table
mDT <- df[!is.na(DX2), .(DX2 = NA_character_, first(ID)), by = DRC1][]
# join with lookup table and update during join
df[mDT, on = .(DX2, DRC1), IDfound := V2][]
```

> ```
>    ID SR1     SR2  DRC1 DX2 Status IDfound
> 1:  1 123 as#12.c ABC-1 SXI   TRUE      NA
> 2:  2 124 ae&14.v ABC-1 SXI   TRUE      NA
> 3:  3 125 at$19.e AXX-1  NA   TRUE       4
> 4:  4 125 at$19.d AXX-1 SCV   TRUE      NA
> 5:  5 785 ab&22.n AWZ-2 DDF  FALSE      NA
> 6:  6 849 ab&22.n AWZ-5 DDF  FALSE      NA
> ```

The lookup table `mDT` is used to find matches in the `DX2` and `DRC1` columns. `V2` contains the `ID` of the first row in each `DRC1` group where `DX2` is *not* `NA`.

```
mDT
```

> ```
>     DRC1 DX2 V2
> 1: ABC-1  NA  1
> 2: AXX-1  NA  4
> 3: AWZ-2  NA  5
> 4: AWZ-5  NA  6
> ```

Only those entries of `df` are updated where both `DX2` and `DRC1` match. By joining, it looks for rows where `DRC1` matches and `DX2` is `NA`. If one is found, the corresponding `V2` values is copied to column `IDfound`.

Comment: it really worked fast but it gives me two dataframe `df` and `mDT` instead of one combined `df`.

Comment: But in `df` i am not getting `IDfound` column.

Comment: It gives me correct `Status` but not giving `IDfound`.

Comment: Is it because it gives less row in `mDT` than `df`??

Comment: At a glance, I think the issue here is that the last line returns the full set including `IDfound` to the console, but does not assign it. Changing the last line to `df <- df[mDT, on = .(DRC1)][is.na(DX2), IDfound := V1][, V1 := NULL]` should give the expected results.

Comment: @MattSummersgill it worked but all the value in `IDfound` column in `NA` now though i have correct value in `mDT`.

Comment: @Uwe It gives me `Status` as "False" where there is only one row against unique `DRC1`. Well that i'll take care.

Comment: @Uwe in `mDT` IDfound value is wrong i think its just giving numbering in `V1` starting from 1 to n

Comment: @MattSummersgill, @VectorJX Sorry for the hassle, I was in a rush. I believe I have fixed the two issues with creating the correct values for `IDfound` (at least for the sample data set.)

Comment: @Uwe Thanks., but in i think you misunderstood, in `IDfound` i want only those entry where i have `DRC1` value but don't have `DX2`. but while looping i found `DX2` value corresponding to `DRC1` value. As per the test data set i don't have `DX2` value for Row 3 but while looping i found `DX2` value corresponding to `DRC1` value of row 3, and in `IDfound` column i am showing that for missing `DX2` value of row 3 i should look at row 4.

Comment: By looping you mean that you call `StatusJudge()` for each `DRC1` one group, right? In the lookup table `mDT`, `V2` contains the `ID` of the first row in each `DRC1` group where `DX2` is *not* `NA`.

Comment: @VectorJX, as you have accepted the answer, does it return the correct result now? And, how is the speedup?